# how to remove Required * in helper text in date picker in mui

Tags: reactjs, validation, material-ui, react-hook-form, mui-x

I'm new to react and Mui I was working with  validating a form in react with react-hook-form.

in `DatePicker` `helperText`  field I need to remove required *  when user saves

when I input date how can I do it I'm leaving codeSandBox  [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reacthookform-ds5nxl?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js)
after that I need to validate for `radio Button` , `dropdown`, `checkboxes` how can I do using `react-hook-form` and `Mui` sorry my English is week and if I made any mistakes

Comment: Don't you think `inputRef={register('DateOfBirth',{ required:'Required *' })}` is the problem?

Comment: where to put that statement then?